# Android get ephemeris data and gnss measurements

Tags: android, android-gps

I am developing an Android app as a beginner, after reading http://gpsworld.com/innovation-precise-positioning-using-raw-gps-measurements-from-android-smartphones/.

1. I  have a LG V20 to try. However, the app reports that the gps
   chip on LG V20 is 2015 and not able to provide gnssmeasurements.
   Does anyone know which phone on the market now supports
   gnssmeasurements with a matching gps chip?
2. How do we extract ephemeris data from android api? My LG V20 runs
   Nougat OS, but attempting to register gnssNavigationMessage listener
   gives STATUS_UNKNOWN. Is gnssNavigationMessage the correct API for
   ephemeris data?

Answer (score 2):

The article in gpsworld.com that you are referring to tells that Nexus 9 tablet, Nexus 5x phone, Nexus 6p phone, Pixel phone and the Pixel XL phone support GNSS raw measurements.

See https://github.com/google/gps-measurement-tools/releases for an example application, GnssLogger.

I use Nexus 5x and Android 7.0 and it supports GnssMeasurements but it does not support GnssNavigationMessages so you cannot get ephemeris data.